# VS2022 not loading local nuget symbols

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-2022

Created a class library locally, successfully packaged it, loaded it up in my project via nuget package manager, it works great.

I'm trying to debug from my project, and it's complaining that symbols do not exist for these files when trying to add a breakpoint.

The symbols package is being created: I have `EfVueMantle.1.0.12.nupkg` and `EfVueMantle.1.0.12.snupkg` both in the same directory. Changing the version number and repackaging creates both as expected, and I can update my project via nuget package manager.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling my package.

I've tried unloading and reloading the project.

I've tried opening and closing VS2022 at basically every step of this process.

I'm under the impression that installing the .nupkg will automatically discover the .snupkg file, but perhaps that is a misconception?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported yet.

For details see https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8809